# How to load images/videos directly from server in Blazor WebAssembly?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, blazor-webassembly

I implemented a solution in Blazor webassembly that allows the user to upload an image and store the file on the server and the filepath in the database. When I load the image on client I send the image from the sever to client as bytes and transform the image bytes in a base64 string and display the image. This works well but from what I read, this is not a good practice because the base64 tranformation is increasing the file size by 30% and the images cannot be cached on client. I would want to let the browser download the file from the server path and display the image. My questions are the following:

1. How do I set the server 'root' location in order for the browser to know where to get the files ? I'm using IWebHostEnvironment on the server to get the local path.
2. Is there any way to secure the files to allow only the authorised user to download the files from the server ?
3. Should I add the images in the same folder as the solution or I should make a different folder outside of the solution ?

I'm currently using IIS Server with ASP.NET CORE 5 in a Blazor WebAssembly solution.

EDIT 1:

Controller method:

```
  [HttpGet(API.GetFile)]
    public async Task<FileContentResult> GetFile([FromQuery] string fileType,string encoding,string name)
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(_webHost.ContentRootPath, "Media", "Images", name);
        byte[] file = await System.IO.File.ReadAllBytesAsync(path);

        return File(file, encoding);
    }
```

Link used to access the file :

> https://localhost:44339/GetFile?encoding=image/jpeg&name=3020_1_21.JPEG

Generated tag in the browser:

```
<img style="width:300px;height:300px" src="https://localhost:44339/GetFile?encoding=image/jpeg&name=3020_1_21.JPEG">
```

As I mentioned in comments, the link works in Postman, it retrives the image, but it does not work in the browser, there is no file retrieved.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `transform the image bytes in a base64 string and display the image.` there's no reason to do this. Just return the bytes from a URL and have the `<image>` or `<video>` element point to that link. Using `File(imageBytes, "image/jpeg");` with the correct content type is enough. You could load the entire BLOB from the database and return it, or use SqlClient's stream support

Comment: That's no different from displaying a static image. In both cases the server loads the bytes and sends them to the browser with a specific content type. The browser doesn't care how the bytes were loaded

Comment: It *is* a good practice to store frequently used files on disk and return these instead of always hitting the database. Quite often it's a good practice to store files locally, eg into a temp folder, and return their contents, especially if they're large.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have created a api get method to return the image, just as you said, and I bumped into a weird issue, the link that i created that returns the image works in Postman but it does not work in browser. I edited the question, if you have any ideea why is this happening it would be great.

Comment: Nevermind, I restarted Visual Studio and the browser and now it works. You can post the answer so I can mark it as correct.